# mockResolvedValueOnce return promise intead of given value

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

```
import products from "services/products";

jest.mock("services/products", () => {
    return {
        getProducts: jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve([product, product])),
    };
});

((products.getProducts as unknown) as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce([product, product]);
```

Why is this array of **[product, product]** when it gets to the code it's **Promise {[product, product]}** 
And as a result i recive an error on that array map (array.map is not a function)

Comment: How did you call `products.getProducts()` method?

Comment: expect(products.getProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();

Answer (score 1):

```
jest.mock("services/products", () => {
    return {
        getProducts: jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(() => [product, product]),
    };
});
```

I needed to remove Promise.resolve() from jest mock function because i was not moching a promise and also i needed to delete this like as well because it was redundant:

```
((products.getProducts as unknown) as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce([product, product]);
```